# How does retaining fragment instance with setRetainInstance(true) work?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment without view which I use to host an AsyncTask. I want to retain the fragment object during configuration changes (eg. orientation change). To my understanding using setRetainInstance(true) in the onCreate() method of the fragment should be enough. But here is my problem:

First of let me post some code I'm using.

My activity uses this in its onCreate() method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedState);

    /* omitted - other initialization that takes place */

    fetcher = (DirectionsFetcherFragment)
        manager.findFragmentByTag(DIRECTIONS_FETCHER_FRAGMENT);
        if (fetcher == null)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Creating new DirectionsFetcherFragment instance");

            fetcher = DirectionsFetcherFragment.newInstance( /*omitted*/);

            transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(fetcher, DIRECTIONS_FETCHER_FRAGMENT);
            transaction.commit();
        }
}
```

and here are some samples from the fragment code

```
class DirectionsFetcherFragment extends Fragment
{
    /* string constants omitted */


    public static DirectionsFetcherFragment newInstance(/*omitted*/)
    {
        DirectionsFetcherFragment instance = new DirectionsFetcherFragment();
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        /* omitted - adding the necessary data to the bundle */
        instance.setArguments(data);
        return instance;
    }

    public DirectionsFetcherFragment()
    {
        super();
        /* omitted - setting default values for member variables */
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
    {
        Log.wtf(TAG, "onCreate()");
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        Bundle arguments = getArguments();

        /* omitted - other initializations tasks that take place */
    }
}
```

Here's what's happening. On the initial activity creation the fetcher reference is null as expected and thus I create a new fragment and add it via a transaction. When/if I rotate the device though, when the activity's onCreate() method runs the fetcher reference is null, no fragment is returned by findFragmentByTag(). In the LogCat I can clearly see that the fragment's onDetach() -> onAttach() methods are run for the first fragment, but for some reason the fragment is then garbage collected and a new fragment is created.

Here is the LogCat output:

```
D/DirectionsViewer﹕ Initializing from intent <<-- Initial activity creation
D/DirectionsViewer﹕ Creating new DirectionsFetcherFragment instance <<-- Fragment creation
A/DirectionsFetcherFragment﹕ onAttach()
A/DirectionsFetcherFragment﹕ onCreate()
V/DirectionsViewer﹕ onStart()
V/DirectionsViewer﹕ onResume()
V/DirectionsViewer﹕ onSaveInstanceState() <<-- Rotationing and saving instance
A/DirectionsFetcherFragment﹕ onDetach() <<-- Fragment correctly detaches
D/DirectionsViewer﹕ Restoring from saved instance <<-- Activity restoration
D/DirectionsViewer﹕ Creating new DirectionsFetcherFragment instance <<-- Why is this happenning, shouldn't I get a reference to the existing fragment?
A/DirectionsFetcherFragment﹕ onAttach()
A/DirectionsFetcherFragment﹕ onCreate()
V/DirectionsViewer﹕ onStart()
V/DirectionsViewer﹕ onResume()
V/DirectionsViewer﹕ Deleting DirectionsViewer instance <<-- This is the old activity that gets garbage collected
A/DirectionsFetcherFragment﹕ Deleting DirectionsFetcherFragment instance <<-- This is the old fragment instance that gets garbage collected
```

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance for any answers.